# Detect if Page was redirected from RedirectToAction() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Here are my ActionResult methods :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
    {
        LastTwoParameters lastTwoParameters = new LastTwoParameters();
        lastTwoParameters.listCities = Common.GetDropDownCitiesList();
        lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = new List<getReport_LastTwo_Result>();

        // if IsPostBack , then execute

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityID) && days > 0)
        {
            using (KQXS context = new KQXS())
            {
                lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = context.getReport_LastTwo(cityID, numbers, days, onlySpecial).ToList();
            }
        }


        return View(lastTwoParameters);
    }

    [HttpPost]//Run action method on form submission
    public ActionResult Index(List<Cities> listCities, string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "LastTwo", new{cityID = cityID, numbers = numbers, days = days, onlySpecial = onlySpecial});
    }
```

What I need is to detect if the page is called from a `RedirectToAction` method. Because I don't have the need to calculate the result the first time the user open the page.

Comment: Why don't you make use of `TempData`? set it before RedirectToAction like `TempData['Redirection'] = true` and check for Tempdata value in the above for `null` or `true`

Comment: @TRR perfect, it worked. Would you mind posting your comment as the answer so I can mark it? Thanks alot!

Comment: beware not to read the TempData anywhere else but there. It becomes null on first read. if you want to check it in multiple places, use `Tempdata.Keep()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve your issue.

1. You could use service side caching. Controller has TempData property. 
   Simply set to the TempData["wasRedirected"] = true. And after your first read from the framework will clear the value. In your case TempData["wasRedirected"] == null means that your code was not redirected.
2. You could use url params for example you action:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(bool? wasRedirected)
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

   And in redirect method you will have code like this:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Redirect()
   {
       return this.RedirectToAction("Index", new { wasRedirected = true });
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi I solved it based on TRR's comment. Anyway, nice answer though!

Comment: I am glad you included the new { parm } option. I had a weird situation where TempData couldn't be used.

Answer (score 5):

In an `ActionFilter` or by overriding the `OnAction{Executing, Executed}` on the controller you can check the type of the `ActionResult` class.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) 
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```